# Why does Style not work proper on Popup in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, styles

I am not sure if i do not use the correct way, so I try to describe my case here. Please help to point out the detail.

The purpose of mine is to customize the WPF `Popup` class and implement a specific popup panel. I use the CustomControl to implement this as below:

Here is the `Generic.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CCPopup}">
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Child">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Border Background="Red"
                        Width="30"
                        Height="30" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and the following is the code, which only register the meta style information:

```
public class CCPopup : Popup
{
    static CCPopup()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CCPopup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CCPopup)));
    }
}
```

The problems I met until now can be summarized as below:

1) I try to write:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CCPopup}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Popup}}">
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Child">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Border Background="Red"
                        Width="30"
                        Height="30" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But this does not works, and I got the error `{x:Type Popup}` could not be resolved. Why?

About my MainWindow.xaml: I only add `<CCPopup x:Key="popup" />` in its resource and create a button, when I click the button, I bind the popup's `PlacementTarget` to this button and set popup's `IsOpen` property to true in code.

2) When I create a instance of CCPopup in the code, such as `CCPopup p = new CCPopup()`, some of the Style does not works, such as `AllowsTransparency` and `StaysOpen`, will not be set to the value I give in the xaml Style. But when I create a instance from xaml `<CCPopup x:Key="popup" />` and refer to it from resource in code, the style works correctly. Can you point out where I made a mistake ?

3) Just curious about why `Popup` class do not have `Template` property?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Popup doesn't have Template property because it doesn't inherit from Control class.

Comment: Can you write your MainWindow.xaml? I think you wrote the ResourceDictionary.xaml, and it would be good if you copy your MainWindow xaml code.

Comment: Shouldn't your `BasedOn` property be part of the `<Style>` tag, and not the `<Setter>` tag?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake of BasedOn and I also give MainWindow.xaml 's description here.